# Unit Testing with libgdx and own GameText Class

Tags: libgdx

I have created a GameTest Class for extending my Testclasses, but when I use them I get the following error:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx64.dll' for target: Windows 8.1, 64-bit
```

My Class:

```
public class GameTest {
    // This is our "test" application
    private static Application application;

    // Before running any tests, initialize the application with the headless backend
    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        // Note that we don't need to implement any of the listener's methods
        application = new HeadlessApplication(new ApplicationListener() {
            @Override public void create() {}
            @Override public void resize(int width, int height) {}
            @Override public void render() {}
            @Override public void pause() {}
            @Override public void resume() {}
            @Override public void dispose() {}
        });

        // Use Mockito to mock the OpenGL methods since we are running headlessly
        Gdx.gl20 = Mockito.mock(GL20.class);
        Gdx.gl = Gdx.gl20;
    }

    // After we are done, clean up the application
    @AfterClass
    public static void cleanUp() {
        // Exit the application first
        application.exit();
        application = null;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me in which direction I should solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not add the libgdx test dependencies to your "build.gradle" file.
Try adding these dependencies to the “core” section:

```
        testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
        testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.2.29"

        testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
        testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

        // box2d dependencies if necessary
        testCompile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        testCompile  "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
```